# Centered image and add font size not working

Tags: html, css

I want the image to be in big size and centered, it seems size and to be shown centered still not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="content-grid">
  <img src="test.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-grid img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadasjad/1aedjv7s/

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: seems the image is not centered and enlarge

Comment: Are you expecting `font-size` to alter the image size??

Comment: for that increase the em value as much as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadasjad/1aedjv7s/

```
.content-grid img{
display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    /* font-size: 255%; */
    width: 33em;
}
```

if you need more size, increase the em value width as much as you want.
for example, change `width: 33em;` to `width: 50em;`, `width: 65em;`